# What is the best way to get the best fit for a set of 2D points, that generate a curved line?

Tags: approximation, regression, smooth-functions

I am trying to fit a set of 2D points into a curved line. I have tried polynomial regression, and it worked for simple lines, but there are a lot of cases when the [Runge's phenomenom](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Runge%27s_phenomenon) appears, and also when I have higher polynomial orders I get Nan values.

I am wondering what is the best approximation algorithm that I can use.

Comment: Could you post some data ? Did you think about parametric splines ?

Comment: The data is mainly 2D points from different rivers, but I have multiple points in some area and I want an approximate fit. I tried Cubic Spline, but as I've said it went through all the points which isn't the wanted behaviour.

Comment: Also I posted here (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65370324/how-to-generate-the-best-curved-fit-for-a-set-of-2d-points-in-c) some example